# SQL Server DB auto growth not working

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql server db enterprise version. I have set auto growth size to 500MB for both files and max size unlimited but some times it is not working and DB does not respond properly.

Means it stops auto growth of db files, it is same as initial size.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

A likely cause is the auto grow operation times out and rolls back because the SQL Server service account doesn't have the Windows permission "Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks" needed for [instant file initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization).

That said, you should use use auto grow only as a safety net for unexpected space needs. It is best to size files according to expected space requirements to avoid auto grow.